# How can I use the <code> element to display certain computer code, without my page breaking?

Tags: html, css, unicode, formatting

I'm creating a technical documentation page with HTML and CSS.

I'm trying to include code and I'm having trouble adding some of it without my page breaking.

For example, this works just fine and doesn't break:

```
<code>
  return number * number;
</code>
```

But this breaks, how can I add code like this?

```
  <code>
    var n = 0; var x = 0; while (n < 3) { n++; x +=n; }
  </code>
```

please help!! thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the "less than" sign. Since it is used as the starting character of an HTML tag.

You can solved this in two ways:

1. Use CDATA tag - find out more here -> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_cdata_sections.htm
2. Change it to an HTML entity "<" - find out more here -> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your "less than" sign into an entity. HTML uses that sign to indicate the start of a tag. In this case, the entity for this sign would be:

```
&lt;
```

Result:

```html
<code>
var n = 0; var x = 0; while (n &lt; 3) { n++; x +=n; }
</code>
```